# Keep alive header and Web API

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I am not able to set the keep-alive in the response header with the web Api. I am running in the IIS Express(Development server). I am using the message handler which sets the same

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            var NonAuthenicateresponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            NonAuthenicateresponse.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("NTLM"));
            return NonAuthenicateresponse;
        }

        var response=await base.SendAsync(request,cancellationToken);

        response.Headers.ConnectionClose = false;
        return response;
    }
```

Am i missing anything extra parameter for the same.

To add more details , I am trying to implement NTLM authentication for the application. Once the request is made from the browser we issue a 401 unauthorized and the negotiation happening but it is able to send the Authorization header back in the subsequent request.

We need to explicitly say to the browser about the Keep-alive the connection.

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  Keep-alive behavior is the default in HTTP/1.1.  Setting ConnectionClose=false will cause no connection header to appear.

Comment: You only want the Connection: close header to appear when you want to force the client to close the connection after it has received the response.

Comment: @DarrelMiller i was working on NTLM and i am facing the problem on that